# What's the significance of this pattern?

Tags: mathematics, number-property

*Note, this is my first submission, let me know if I broke the rules.*

What is the significance of the following sequence of # signs?

```
   #
 #
    #
 #
     #
         #
  #
      #
     #
   #
     #
        #
         #
       #
         #
   #
  #
   #
        #
    #
      #
  #
      #
    #
   #
   #
        #
   #
  #
       #
         #
     #
#
  #
        #
        #
    #
 #
         #
       #
 #
      #
         #
   #
         #
         #
   #
       #
     #
 #
#
     #
        #
  #
#
         #
       #
    #
         #
    #
    #
     #
         #
  #
   #
#
       #
        #
 #
      #
    #
#
      #
  #
        #
      #
  #
#
        #
         #
         #
        #
      #
  #
        #
#
   #
    #
        #
  #
     #
   #
    #
  #
 #
 #
       #
#
      #
       #
         #
        #
  #
 #
    #
        #
#
        #
      #
     #
 #
   #
  #
        #
  #
   #
#
      #
      #
    #
       #
#
         #
   #
        #
    #
    #
      #
#
         #
     #
     #
#
     #
        #
  #
  #
   #
 #
       #
  #
     #
   #
     #
         #
    #
#
        #
 #
  #
        #
    #
        #
 #
 #
 #
       #
    #
     #
#
  #
        #
    #
 #
#
  #
       #
#
 #
         #
   #
        #
     #
  #
 #
 #
#
     #
     #
     #
         #
      #
    #
    #
      #
  #
  #
         #
    #
        #
         #
     #
    #
         #
   #
#
   #
        #
 #
         #
      #
    #
    #
  #
        #
        #
 #
#
         #
       #
     #
      #
      #
     #
         #
   #
   #
    #
    #
      #
 #
  #
        #
    #
       #
     #
      #
    #
        #
  #
   #
   #
       #
        #
      #
       #
        #
   #
 #
      #
     #
  #
       #
 #
  #
#
 #
         #
#
         #
 #
    #
     #
      #
    #
        #
     #
      #
      #
         #
  #
   #
    #
      #
#
   #
    #
        #
      #
 #
#
    #
     #
    #
   #
  #
      #
      #
    #
        #
  #
 #
   #
   #
         #
   #
      #
#
       #
  #
      #
#
  #
    #
         #
 #
    #
 #
  #
       #
   #
       #
  #
    #
     #
        #
       #
#
#
      #
      #
#
      #
   #
 #
     #
     #
        #
        #
 #
       #
    #
        #
        #
 #
     #
  #
#
         #
  #
#
         #
      #
  #
        #
  #
         #
  #
     #
    #
#
         #
 #
       #
 #
     #
   #
      #
    #
   #
      #
       #
        #
         #
  #
     #
         #
#
   #
      #
#
#
 #
 #
   #
   #
#
     #
   #
#
     #
    #
        #
        #
  #
#
    #
      #
      #
     #
  #
 #
   #
        #
    #
 #
    #
      #
         #
     #
 #
         #
    #
 #
     #
 #
 #
      #
#
         #
    #
   #
   #
#
     #
       #
  #
       #
#
   #
      #
     #
       #
     #
         #
     #
         #
 #
         #
     #
   #
#
         #
  #
 #
        #
      #
 #
 #
       #
   #
        #
 #
         #
   #
  #
      #
 #
 #
       #
         #
   #
 #
#
     #
 #
 #
        #
     #
    #
        #
#
       #
    #
    #
      #
  #
   #
       #
         #
         #
      #
  #
       #
    #
         #
     #
      #
       #
   #
     #
 #
        #
        #
     #
       #
     #
  #
       #
  #
    #
        #
         #
 #
  #
  #
       #
         #
   #
        #
 #
        #
   #
#
 #
 #
         #
    #
         #
 #
  #
         #
        #
   #
   #
      #
       #
   #
   #
      #
  #
    #
    #
#
      #
     #
      #
      #
    #
   #
#
        #
      #
#
  #
 #
   #
         #
    #
         #
    #
      #
   #
         #
     #
  #
  #
    #
       #
   #
       #
 #
         #
#
       #
#
  #
 #
       #
         #
        #
      #
#
         #
    #
   #
       #
#
  #
       #
       #
#
     #
   #
         #
  #
 #
       #
 #
       #
```

**Hint:**

> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think

> The spaces before the number sign represent the first 570 (569 after the decimal) digits of pi.
>  Happy pi day!

Comment: Yeah, I probably should've waited a day, huh? Haha, I didn't notice someone already did a similar challenge. Nice catch though :). How does answer accepting work-- first person with the right answer gets a tick?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The person with the best answer gets the tick. It normally goes like: Best answer > First answer > An answer. If you are happy that this is the best answer possible (within reason) then you should accept it!

Comment: @Adam it's not really subjective here! I'll wait a bit though, I didn't make any mistakes right? I've followed this SE for awhile without participating.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn You've done everything right! I was generalising to help you in the case that you make a more subjective puzzle. It's really up to you when you accept an answer and what qualifies as an answer. As long as the accepted answer isn't ridiculous, the community will support your decision. Normally you wait for answers when you've either asked a question that you don't know the answer to or if it is an optimisation/subjective puzzle etc

Comment: @adam thanks! Im a frequent on programming puzzles and code golf where subjective answers arent allowed so this is new. I'll keep this in mind and actually go give the rules a thorough read now that I have time.